# Configure main domain and sub domain with diffrent resourcs in apache server

Tags: apache, subdomain

I have an issue to creating a sub domain  in apache server.
 Normally we can do that by following way.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.maindomain.com
  ServerAlias *.maindomain.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/abc/xyz"
  <Directory "/home/abc/xyz">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In above example both main and sub domain share same Directory.

But my requirement is main domain have its own resource and rest of sub domains have other resource.

I want to do something like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.maindomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/abc/xyz"
    <Directory "/home/abc/xyz">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xyz.maindomain.com
    ServerAlias *.maindomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/ghi/pqr"
    <Directory "/home/ghi/pqr">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Above thing didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use apache VirtualDocumentRoot.

Answer (score 0):

Does the `NameVirtualHost` directive (for example, `NameVirtualHost *:80`) appear in your Apache configuration file, before the virtual hosts? If not, it needs to be there.